# Combine two PHP mysql_fetch_assoc sets of MySQL multidimensional arrays into one single-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

Would greatly appreciate any help with this.

I'm running two `mysql_query`'s to retrieve an array of **total bulletins** for a specified user in a database from one table (`bulletins`) and **signed bulletins** from a second table (`bulletins_sign_log`).

The problem I'm running into is how to determine out of the two arrays, which bulletins still require signature from a user.

Here's the example arrays and my attempts so far:

**total bulletins** `mysql_query` PHP code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT b.id AS bulletin_id FROM bulletins b WHERE 
(b.to_user_id='username' OR b.to_group_id='0')");

while($total_bulletins[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
```

**total bulletins** `print_r` result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bulletin_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bulletin_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => 
)
1
```

**signed bulletins** `mysql_query` PHP code

```php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT s.bulletin_id FROM bulletins_sign_log s WHERE
s.username_id='username'");

while($signed_bulletins[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
```

**signed bulletins** `print_r` result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bulletin_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => 
)
1
```

This is where I can't figure out how to determine that *bulletin # 3* from **total bulletins** hasn't been signed by the user. I've tried using `array_diff()` but didn't get the expected result.

**comparison** `array_diff` PHP code

```
$unsigned = array_diff($total_bulletins, $signed_bulletins);
```

**comparison** `print_r` result

```
Array
(
)
1
```

My ultimate goal is to take the value of the unsigned `bulletin_id` (bulletin #3 in this case) and place it into a header redirect if greater than 0 such as:

```php
if($unsigned['0'] > 0){
    header('location: /sign_bulletin.php?bulletin_id='.$unsigned['0'].');
}
```

**final result**

`header('location: /sign_bulletin.php?bulletin_id=1');`

**final (expected) result**

`header('location: /sign_bulletin.php?bulletin_id=3');`

---

**EDIT** Adding some additional information after trying @gilden's suggested SQL query.

**SQL query** that I used in phpMyAdmin

```sql
SELECT b.id 
    FROM bulletins2 b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bulletins_sign_log2 s ON b.id = s.bulletin_id
        AND b.to_user_id = s.username_id
    WHERE s.bulletin_id IS NULL
        AND b.to_user_id = 'username1'
        OR  b.to_group_id = '0'
```

**MySQL result** from phpMyAdmin

```
bulletin_id
          1
          3
```

The problem with the result is that it lists **bulletin_id #1** as not being signed for **username1**. However, in the example `bulletins_sign_log` table below, **username1** has a "signed" record for this bulletin_id. It's being flagged because of the matching SQL statement:

```sql
OR  b.to_group_id = '0'
```

**to_group_id** is not recorded in the **bulletins_sign_log** table as a "group" cannot sign for something but it's members can. It is only logged in the `bulletins` table to know which users to send the bulletin too. In this case, **to_group_id '0'** is the "Everyone" group where all users receive the bulletin.

So my next thought was to just remove `OR  b.to_group_id = '0'` but then I get an empty set. Any ideas on where to go from here with the current database configuration? Changing the DB would mean changing A LOT of code unfortunately then hours or days of debugging possibly.

Would it be possible to go back to the original idea of separate arrays and somehow get them both into an array where duplicate values can be removed? The original method seems to be a working method for getting accurate source information which is a start. This would then leave an array of unique bulletin_id's that have not been signed.

**Table structure** for `bulletins`

```sql
CREATE TABLE bulletins (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `bulletin` longtext NOT NULL,
  `from_user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `to_user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `to_group_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_sent` date NOT NULL,
  `time_sent` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `from_user_id` (`from_user_id`),
  KEY `to_user_id` (`to_user_id`),
  KEY `to_group_id` (`to_group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `bulletins` VALUES(1, 'Subject 1', 'username1', 'username9', 0, 'Text Content 1', '2009-03-15', '20:31:50');
INSERT INTO `bulletins` VALUES(2, 'Subject 2', 'username1', 'username3', 9, 'Text Content 2', '2010-08-17', '12:00:00');
INSERT INTO `bulletins` VALUES(3, 'Subject 3', 'username3', 'username9', 0, 'Text Content 3', '2010-10-13', '16:45:23');
```

**Table structure** for `bulletins_sign_log`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `bulletins_sign_log` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `bulletin_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `username_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `accept_initials` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `accept_date` date NOT NULL,
  `accept_time` time NOT NULL,
  `first_date_read` date NOT NULL,
  `first_time_read` time NOT NULL,
  `last_date_read` date NOT NULL,
  `last_time_read` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `username_id` (`username_id`),
  KEY `bulletin_id` (`bulletin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `bulletins_sign_log` VALUES(1, 1, 'username1', 'AB', '2009-03-16', '12:45:10', '2009-03-16', '12:43:09', '2009-03-17', '13:05:11');
INSERT INTO `bulletins_sign_log` VALUES(2, 2, 'username5', 'CD', '2010-08-19', '00:28:07', '0000-00-00', '00:00:00', '0000-00-00', '00:00:00');
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

---

**FINAL code** with **@gilden**'s help - Thanks!

It didn't make sense for the original sender to have to sign his own bulletin so I blocked that as a requirement from the SQL query by adding:

```sql
AND b.from_user_id != 'username1'
```

**WARNING** Be sure to add that to the bottom of the query or it won't work - trust me.

...and here's the final SQL query:

```sql
SELECT b.id AS bulletin_id
    FROM bulletins b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bulletins_sign_log s ON b.id = s.bulletin_id
        AND b.to_user_id = s.username_id
    WHERE s.bulletin_id IS NULL
        AND b.to_user_id = 'username1'
        OR  b.to_group_id = '0'
        AND b.from_user_id != 'username1'
```

...and the **PHP code**

```php
$sql = "SELECT b.id AS bulletin_id FROM bulletins b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bulletins_sign_log s ON b.id = s.bulletin_id 
AND b.to_user_id = s.username_id WHERE s.bulletin_id IS NULL 
AND b.to_user_id = '$username' OR  b.to_group_id = '0' 
AND b.from_user_id != '$username'";

$query = mysql_query($sql);

$unsigned = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$value = $unsigned['0'];

if($value > 0){
    header('location: /bulletin_notice.php?bulletin_id='.$value.'');
}
else{
    $value = 0;
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `JOIN` to get the unsigned bulletins?

```sql
SELECT b.id 
    FROM bulletins b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bulletins_sign_log s ON b.id = s.bulletin_id
        AND b.to_user_id = s.username_id
    WHERE s.bulletin_id IS NULL
        AND b.to_user_id = 'username'
        OR  b.to_group_id = '0'
```

This should retrieve all the rows in `bulletins` that are not in `bulletins_signed`. If both the signed and unsigned bulletins have exactly the same fields, you should store them in a single table. An additional field would store if a bulletin is signed or not insetad.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @gilden. I tried your code and didn't get a result but I think this is because my `bulletins_signed` table doesn't have a NULL record for each corresponding bulletin that hasn't been signed by the user. It only keeps a record once the bulletin has been signed. So I'm pretty sure this method would work if the DB was setup that way. Any suggestion for it's current configuration (no NULL values for unsigned bulletins)?

Comment: @SirOracle No, a left join should return all rows from the "left" table (`bulletins`), even if it doesn't find any matching records on the "right" table (`bulletins_signed`). It should return all the values form the left table, plus matched values from the right table (or NULL in the case of no matching join predicate), but since we're limiting `s.bulletin_id` to be NULL, we're essentially getting all left table's rows that do not have a corresponding row in `bulletins_signed`. Did you try running the query straight on the MySQL server?

Comment: Ah, thanks for correcting my ignorance on 'IS NULL'. I did try the code directly in phpMyAdmin through SQL query and it returned an empty set. So I played around with it a little thinking I might have to add a specific user since the native command was probably looking at all bulletins vs. all signed. If that's the case it would be empty as other users have signed "bulletin #3" which would make it a match for that row. Given that, I've added some new information to the original question that shows latest results and table structures.

Comment: @SirOracle Ah yes, that is probably the case. I have updated my query to consider the fact that several different users can sign the same bulletin. Could you try the new version?

Comment: Thank you for you help. I updated the question above with the latest results which still has a small "qwerk" but I think I figured it out. I needed to exclude the original sender on the check for signatures as he wouldn't have to sign his own bulletin.

Posted the final code above since I can't format it here. Thanks again @gilden.